# corrupted stack

Tags: c++

This is my function and it says

> stack around variable cinfo was corrupted.

and it says that problem is in line 551 which is last line in this posted code.

```
struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;
struct jpeg_error_mgr       jerr;

FILE*      pOutFile;     //Target file 
int        nSampsPerRow; //Physical row width in image buffer 
JSAMPARRAY jsmpArray;    //Pixel RGB buffer for JPEG file

cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr); //Use default error handling (ugly!)

jpeg_create_compress(&cinfo);

if ((pOutFile = fopen(csJpeg, "wb")) == NULL)
{
    *pcsMsg = "Cannot open ";
    *pcsMsg += csJpeg;
    jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);
    return FALSE;
}

jpeg_stdio_dest(&cinfo, pOutFile);

LPBITMAPINFOHEADER lpbi = (LPBITMAPINFOHEADER)hDib;

cinfo.image_width      = lpbi->biWidth;  //Image width and height, in pixels 
cinfo.image_height     = lpbi->biHeight;
cinfo.input_components = 3;              //Color components per pixel
                                         //(RGB_PIXELSIZE - see jmorecfg.h)
cinfo.in_color_space   = JCS_RGB;        //Colorspace of input image

jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);

jpeg_set_quality(&cinfo,
                 nQuality, //Quality: 0-100 scale
                 TRUE);    //Limit to baseline-JPEG values

jpeg_start_compress(&cinfo, TRUE);

//JSAMPLEs per row in output buffer
nSampsPerRow = cinfo.image_width * cinfo.input_components; 

//Allocate array of pixel RGB values
jsmpArray = (*cinfo.mem->alloc_sarray)
            ((j_common_ptr) &cinfo,
             JPOOL_IMAGE,
             nSampsPerRow,
             cinfo.image_height);

if (DibToSamps(hDib,
               nSampsPerRow,
               cinfo,
               jsmpArray,
               pcsMsg))
{
    //Write the array of scan lines to the JPEG file
    (void)jpeg_write_scanlines(&cinfo,
                               jsmpArray,
                               cinfo.image_height);
}

jpeg_finish_compress(&cinfo); //Always finish

fclose(pOutFile);

jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo); //Free resources

if (*pcsMsg != "")
    return FALSE;

else
    return TRUE;
}
```

stack trace:>   WindowBitmap.exe!CBitmapFile::JpegFromDib(void * hDib, int nQuality, ATL::CStringT > > csJpeg, ATL::CStringT > > * pcsMsg)  Line 551 + 0x28 bytes C++

error message: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'cinfo' was corrupted.
pcsMsg definition:
     CString*   pcsMsg

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and error message?

Comment: a) What is 'it' that's telling you your stack is corrupt.
b) What are your parameters? That use of pcsMsg looks strange

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `pcsMsg`, and the function prototype. your use of setting pcsMsg looks wrong

Comment: Hi, sorry for dampening your first impression of SO, but this is a duplicate of your previous question, which is not condoned. Instead, closing a question (like your previous one) is supposed to encourage you to improve it. You can edit your previous question and make sure to highlight where the actual problem lies. Note: If the code preview shows a scroll bar its an indicator that you *might* have to trim down the problem a bit further yourself.

Comment: When a question is closed, you should not repost it again (even modified). Instead, edit your previous question and ask for it to be reopened. Posting a new message means there are now duplicates, and people have to spend time cleaning them up and deleting the others. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has details on how StackOverflow is designed to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);
```

frees the memory of an automatic variable, which is freed a second time when `cinfo` goes out of scope.

> The function jpeg_destroy_compress() shall deallocate and release all memory associated with the compression object.